# browserify adding not required files to build

Tags: browserify

Browserify works by walking the require statements building up a dependency tree. My problem is, that I would like to include some other files, that are not required anywhere. Those files would set some global variables, when I build for testing, and I would omit them from production builds.

Is there some option in browserify to achive this?

Answer (score 0):

Add them as entry files:

```
browserify({entries: ['one', 'two', 'three']})

// or
browserify()
  .add('one')
  .add('two')
  .add('three')
```